# Can you visit Bosnia and Herzegovina with a National ID Card?

Tags: bosnia, eu-id-card

I'm currently in Croatia, and I'm very close to the border between Croatia and Bosnia and Herzegovina.

I only have my Schengen ID Card, and I wonder if that's enough for visiting Bosnia and Herzegovina.

Or do I need my international passport which I didn't bring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Bosnia_and_Herzegovina EU citizens can enter using a national ID card (incl. Irish passport card) for a stay of up to 90 days within 180 days

Also

> Citizens of  the Kingdom of Sweden are exempted from the visa
>   requirement when entering, exiting or travelling through Bosnia and
>   Herzegovina to 90 days, for a period of six months, starting from the
>   day of entry.

http://www.mvp.gov.ba/konzularne_informacije/vize/Default.aspx?template_id=16&s1=331&id=5173

Comment: This is correct.  My earlier comment suggested that citizens of only certain Schengen countries could enter BiH with a national ID card, but I was confused.  That is the case for Turkey, not BiH.

Comment: As the person behind that Wiki info, I confirm its accuracy